# history of enrollment / work in Google Classroom

Tags: google-api, google-classroom

I'm trying to produce a history of student work, which works very well unless a student unenrolls or a teacher removes them.

At that point, the connection between the (former) student and their previous work on Classroom assignments seems to be lost.

Is there a record of who was enrolled in a class even after they have been removed?

Comment: Probably need to correlate with the Admin SDK. Per [teacher & student](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/manage-users) page, the student/teacher label is a wrapper on the User Account. Given that there are [notifications](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/push-notifications) for roster changes, I expect you can do this (somehow).

Comment: Is there a way to see past changes? Or can you only wait for new notifications of changes?

Comment: I have no idea - I don't have any way to test `Classroom`,  `AdminDirectory`, or other gsuite administrative code. All I can do is read documentation.